# NodeJS Promise.all is waiting for all components to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to process an array that is composed by objects. Each object has a field which value is an array of numbers. I want to process in async/await way all the components of all array of numbers.

An example of the data is this:

```
const data = [{
  numbers: [1, 2, 3],
}, {
  numbers: [4, 5, 6],
}, {
  numbers: [7, 8, 9],
}];
```

I have implemented this function two ways. First one code is this:

```
const processData1 = async(data) => {
  return Promise.all(data.map(async(d) => {
    const partial = await Promise.all(d.numbers.map(async(n) => {
      console.log('INIT', n);
      const number = await processNumber(n);
      console.log('END', n);
      return number;
    }));
    return partial;
  }));
};
```

Second one is this:

```
const processData2 = async(data) => {
  for (const d of data) {
    for (let n of d.numbers) {
      console.log('INIT', n);
      n = await processNumber(n);
      console.log('END', n);
    }
  }
};
```

What I would expect to see in all cases printed in console is "INIT" and "END" one after another in the correct order. And this is true in the second code function. But in the first one, I see as many INIT as numbers and then all the corresponding END:

```
**** processData1 ****
INIT 1
INIT 2
INIT 3
INIT 4
INIT 5
INIT 6
INIT 7
INIT 8
INIT 9
END 1
END 2
END 3
END 4
END 5
END 6
END 7
END 8
END 9
**** processData2 ****
INIT 1
END 1
INIT 2
END 2
INIT 3
END 3
INIT 4
END 4
INIT 5
END 5
INIT 6
END 6
INIT 7
END 7
INIT 8
END 8
INIT 9
END 9
```

How is this possible? Why is the `await processNumber` waiting for all the numbers to be resolved?

Comment: `d.numbers.map(async(n)...` will create async functions in loop which will execute concurrently, because of which INIT is coming one after the other before each ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have
>   resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

This means the passed promises are all executed in parallel and will complete and resolve only when all are ended. In your example the sub-promises are granted to start in order. In your case they happen to end in the same order but this is not necessarily guaranteed (one may take longer than another and end after).

As for the second example all you're doing is launching and immediately awaiting every single `processNumber(n)` inside a for loop, resulting in each process starting and ending sequentially.

Comment: `Promise.all` doesn't  "launch" any promise

Comment: Looking forward for your answer @Bergi !

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you only await the result of `Promise.all` meaning each promise is executed at the same time. In the second example, you await each individual promise which forces them to be executed in series.

Both scenarios have their uses, first one is better if you don't care about order i.e. operations can be run concurrently, the second one is useful for forcing asynchronous code to execute in order.

Comment: Promises aren't "fired", not by `Promise.all` nor by `await`.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't say they were, I simply said they were fired at the same time (or immediately is probably more accurate).

Comment: In the first example I only use await in the second `Promise.all`, but as I use `return` it should wait it to finish

Comment: @user3748883 The `map` callback function *does* wait for it to finish before logging `END` and resolving the promise returned by the call. But that doesn't stop `map` from calling the callback on every element independently, creating an array of promises immediately.

Comment: @user3748883 not quite, the `numbers.map` creates a promise for each item in the list, which will queue at the same time. Inside each of those promises you have an `await` that will put the second block of code in each Promise back onto the queue, during which time the event loop continues to process other queued code (i.e. all the other Promises). This is why you get all the `INIT` messages first and then all the `END` ones.